# unable to click element with value zero

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click on the div tag that has id="0". Although it can find that id, unable to click on it. clicking on other ids work.
This was working in Firefox 12 but failing in 13
I am using Selenium2 with C#

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='MenuItem' and  @id='0']")).Click();

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 72px; left: 9px; " id="file" class="Menu">
<div class="MenuItem" id="0">&nbsp;<img src="images/UI/Icons/folder.png">Folder</div>
<div class="MenuItem" id="1">&nbsp;<img valign="middle"      src="images/UI/Icons/tree/folderBlogClosed.png">Blog</div>
<div class="MenuItem" id="2">&nbsp;<img valign="middle"   src="images/UI/Icons/folderBoard.png">Discussion Board</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why they have such ID's? It seems to me that your page is not quite ready for automated UI testing. I'd be inclined to get these ID's changed to something more reasonable and reliable. Also, have you tried it with other drivers? Just to see if it's an issue related to the FF Driver.

Comment: When you say Unable to click on that element? Are you getting any exceptions or errors? If any, please can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: There are total 4 menus. I am trying to click first item in the first menu, but it clicks first item in the second menu. I am stunned with this behavior. 
I tried changing the id value to something different , also tried clicking first child element in the div tag that has id=”file” (NEW menu)
In both cases, it just clicks first item in the second menu

Answer (score 1):

Elements with ID attributes that start with numbers are [invalid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name). While most browsers will render this just fine, it's entirely possible that attempting to use JavaScript to locate the element by the ID (as Selenium WebDriver does) will fail.

Comment: @JimEvans- Are you sure that WebDriver uses javascript to locate elements? I think that was done by Selenium 1, and webdriver uses native support by browser.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. The driver uses the findElement Automation Atom for locating elements with every location type except CSS selector and XPath, and it uses JavaScript for both of those as well.

Comment: @JimEvans- For XPath locators, webdriver uses the native support by browser.

Comment: I misspoke in my earlier comment. I meant that the IE driver uses JavaScript for XPath and CSS selectors. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using an XPath and not just selecting by the ID?

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("0"));
```

HTML id's should be unique on a page.

Comment: Does *any* FindElement query (for any element) work? It could be a webdriver + FF13 compatibility issue. I can't test it myself since I don't use Selenium (or C#) regularly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using mouse actions
. Thank you all for your input.

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       IWebElement tagElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='0' and @class='MenuItem']"));
       //mouse hover on first item
       builder.MoveToElement(tagElement).Perform();
        //click on first item
       driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='0' and @class='MenuItem']")).Click();
```